# Does RoboRIO support Java 8?

Tags: microcontroller

My FRC team will recently upgrade from  [CompactRIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactRIO)  to RoboRIO.

CompactRIO only supports up to Java 1.4.
What version of Java does RoboRIO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it supports Java 8 Embedded.

Which basically is Java 8 SE without any graphical library support (because the RoboRio is headless).

Beta teams using Java are currently using Java 8 Embedded for Arm as the JVM on the RoboRio, and Eclipse as the IDE with WPILib provided plugins for project development.